# Где можно найти ЕЦП (цифровую подпись) для тестов?

Tags: php, ssl, x509certificate

Нужна ЕЦП для тестов. Где её можно найти "без регистрации и СМС" ? Без оформления, в общем. Только для тестирования приложения на локалке. Там должен быть файл .cer  и 2 ключа.

Comment: Сгенерировать не?

Comment: Для себя генерировал, используя openssl. Как в руководстве к программе, так и в инете можно найти пошаговую интсрукцию для создания самых разных ецп

Comment: [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/?lang=ru) - буквально на днях прислали спам, что выдают сертификаты на год после подтверждения сайта, больше ничего не просят, проверил, не врут, так и есть.

[WoSing](https://buy.wosign.com/free/) - то же самое, только сертификат на выбор на 1,2,3 года.

Comment: А openssl можно сделать себе тестовый хоть на 100500 лет.